# Commerce Kickstart demo: How do I change the region for the blocks Main Menu and Secondary Menu?

Tags: blocks, theming, commerce

In the [Commerce Kickstart demo](http://demo.commerceguys.com/ck/) the blocks Main Menu and Secondary Menu are assigned to the Menu region. **You can see in the image:**

[image]

But I go to /admin/structure/block these blocks are Disabled. I mean they are not assigne to the menu region

[image]

Is this done programmatically? I need to move the blocks to other region. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Menus are printed in the **region--menu.tpl.php** @ profiles/commerce_kickstart/themes/commerce_kickstart_theme/templates .

You can see the settings for the same in the link admin/appearance/settings/commerce_kickstart_theme

[image]

If you would like to change the positions of menus, then disable the Main Menu & Secondary menu in above link settings as shown in screenshot and enable the blocks using Blocks page.